# JavaScript returns "result" instead of error or exception

Tags: javascript, scope, call

I was testing a very simple code and I was expected to get error but I got a string "result" returned by console!

Here is the code:

```
var person = { name: "Mohammad", last_name: "Kermani"};

var show_person = function (age){
    console.log(this.name +" is "+ age + " years old");
}
```

Now you now we can't use `this.name` when JavaScript does not know what `this` (object) is, then we need to use `call` or `apply`.

Now when I wrote this, I got "result" string *(instead of error or warning)*:

```
show_person(20); //Returns: result is 20 years old
```

See [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kermani/57t9sadr/1/) and what console returns.

The code with `call` should be like:

```
show_person.call(person, 20);  //Returns: Mohammad is 20 years old
```

**What is the string "result" and why JavaScript does not return error when it does not have access to `this.name`?**

**And what will happen if we don't use an object in a function and want to get one of its properties?** *(Like here, I wanted to get name of person object)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: the output of the expression `show_person(20); ` is  is 20 years old in chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that context, `this` refers to the global `window` object. And `window.name` is `"result"` on jsFiddle, as it is the result frame.

Comment: Thanks, Does this mean when I don't tell JavaScript "This is the object you should use" it will use window objects?

Comment: In web browsers, on the load of the page, `this` always points to the  global `window` object. That's why you can access e.g. the `setTimeout()` function, or the `sessionStorage`, etc..

Comment: window is the root Document model OBJECT. everything rest resides within window. Consider it as a browser's window where all your web project lives.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript perfectly knows what this refers to. As long as your function is not enclosed in some particular environment, this reference will point to global object **window**.

Comment: The value of `this` primarily depends on how the function is called, not where it is defined. I don't understand what you mean by *"As long as your function is not enclosed in some particular environment"*.

Comment: Residing in environment means that it's in global namespace rather than any particular one. So, global namespace in JS is window. I don't think I've said somethign unclear

Comment: In `function foo() { function bar() { console.log(this); } bar(); }`, `this` will refer to `window` as well, even though `bar` is not global. But maybe that's not what you meant and I am misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
function Person (opt) {
    this.name = opt.name;
    this.lastName = opt.lastName;
    this.age = opt.age;
}

Person.prototype.showPerson = function () {
    console.log(this.name, 'is', this.age, 'old');
}

var muhammed = new Person({
    name: 'Muhammed',
    lastName: 'Kermani',
    age: 20
});

console.log(muhammed.showPerson());
console.log(muhammed.name);
console.log(muhammed.lastName);
```

Comment: No, I was not. I just did not know why "result" was returning out. Thanks

Comment: No problem. That question was already answered, so this was just to show an example with the correct `this` context. Using call, apply or bind is a needless workaround in your example...

Comment: Thank you. That helps me to understand more

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working piece of code doing what you are trying to achieve :

```
function PersonShower(){
  this.person = { name: "Mohammad", last_name: "Kermani"};

}
PersonShower.prototype.show_person = function (age){
    console.log(this.person.name +" is "+ age + " years old");
}
var p = new PersonShower();
p.show_person(20);
```

The PersonShower is now an object with the person property (which could be passed as a constructor argument)
Then a show_person method is defined for the object prototype.

This way, using this refers to the PersoShower instance.

https://jsfiddle.net/57t9sadr/4/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`window.name` is a reserved reference used to identify window objects. Often used to identify frames for data transport.

JSFiddle uses frame named **result** from which you are getting that reference from. 
By contrast, JSBin uses "JS Bin Output" as `window.name`

By default it's going to be an empty string. This is why window.name will in most browsers be an empty string, which is an going to be an exception comparing to other undefined properties.

[You can learn more about window.name on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

I can see that you seem to understand lexical scope. Let me know if you'd like me to explain how binding and lexical scope works.